# Evaluating $\int_0^B \frac{1}{A^2 + (B^2-x^2)^2}\,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to solve the following integral:

$$\int_0^B \frac{1}{A^2 + (B^2-x^2)^2}\,dx$$

However the polynomial have imaginary roots:

$$-(-i A + B^2)^{1/2},\; (-i A + B^2)^{1/2},\; -(i A + B^2)^{1/2},\;(i A + B^2)^{1/2}$$

I am only interested on the solution from $0$ to $B$. How should I proceed?

Comment: Why did you find the roots?

Comment: I thought i could do it with the classic method for rational functions.

Answer (score 4):

Let $p=\sqrt{1+\frac{A^2}{B^4}}$ and substitute  $x=Bt$
$$I=\int_0^B \dfrac{1}{A^2 + (B^2-x^2)^2} dx
= \frac1{B^3} \int_0^1 \dfrac{1}{t^4-2t^2+p^2} dt
$$
Decompose  the integrand as

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{t^4-2t^2+p^2} = \frac1{2ps}\left( \frac{t+s}{t^2+st+p}- \frac{t-s}{t^2-st+p}\right)
\end{align}
with $s=\sqrt{2(p+1)}$. Then, integrate to obtain
$$I= \frac{1}{4B^3p}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{2(p+1)}}
\ln\frac {\sqrt{1+p}+\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{1+p}-\sqrt{2}}
+ \sqrt{\frac2{p-1}}\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac2{p-1}}\right)
$$

Comment: Aren't you tired to provide good answers ? (joke). Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using the variable change $x\to Bx$, one can immediately reduce to the case $B=1$. If $A$ is real, we have:

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1\frac1{A^2+(1-x^2)^2}dx&=\frac1{2Ai}\int_0^1\left[\frac1{(x^2-1)-Ai}-\frac1{(x^2-1)+Ai}\right]dx\\
&=\frac1A\Im\left(\int_0^1\frac1{(x^2-1)-Ai}dx\right)\\
&=\frac1A\Im\left(\frac1{2\sqrt{1+Ai}}\int_0^1\left[\frac1{x-\sqrt{1+Ai}}-\frac1{x+\sqrt{1+Ai}}\right]dx\right),
\end{align*}

where $\Im$ denotes the imaginary part. This then just reduces to the sum of a few logarithms.

Alternatively, from the second line we may immediately obtain:
\begin{align*}
\frac1A\Im\left(\int_0^1\frac1{(x^2-1)-Ai}dx\right)&=\frac1A\Im\left(\frac1{\sqrt{1+Ai}}\arctan\left(\frac 1{\sqrt{1+Ai}}\right)\right).\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks, it is possible to separate the imaginary part from the solution? Also, I didn't really understand the passage from first to second line, how do you take off the second term from the subtraction?

Comment: The second term is the complex conjugate of the first term. Also, it is possible to separate the imaginary from the real part, since you can express these complex logarithms explicitly in the form $X+Yi$. However, that is a lot of work...

Answer (score -2):

I don't think those roots are correct.  Any complex roots of a polynomial with real coefficients must come in complex conjugate pairs.  If a+ bi and a- bi are roots then two factors are (x- a- bi) and (x- a+ bi) and their product is $(x-a)^2- (bi)^2= x^2- 2ax+ a^2+b^2$ and that will give a "partial fraction" of the form $\frac{Ax+ B}{x^2- 2ax+ a^2+ b^2}$.

Comment: Those are the correct roots.